# How do I force install an application in Linux with input option I?

Tags: linux, unix, amazon-ec2

I am trying install an application in single command. The application gives the following options
`Actions:
 <I> start installation to hard disk
 <H> help
 <Q> quit`

My option is `<I>`. So, how do I enter this `<I>` in single command?

`sudo ./install-tl` this is my command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since texlive is an interactive perl script you can't give an option `I` to the command. But there is an other way to install it.

First install with command `sudo ./install-tl` it will generate `texlive.profile`. Apply this profile file while installing the texlive like the following

`sudo ./install-tl --profile texlive.profile`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:
`echo I | sudo ./install-tl`